# Cron job vs Advanced Python Scheduler

Tags: python, cron

If you want to run your python script, let's say every day at 6 pm, is it better to go with a crontab entry or with a Advanced Python Scheduler solution regarding to power, memory, cpu ... consumption?

In my eyes doing a crone job is therefore better, because I do not see the advantage of permanently running an Advanced Python Scheduler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably use `cron` if two conditions are met;

1. It is available on all platforms your code needs to run on.
2. Starting a script on a set time is sufficient for your needs.

Mirroring these are two reasons to build your own solution:

1. Your program needs to be portable across many operating systems, including those that don't have `cron` available. (like ms-windows)
2. You need to schedule things in a way other than on a set start time. E.g. on a set interval, or if some other condition it met.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed cron is better from resources point of view.
From functional point of view cronjob is better if your requirement is to just run a script at a specific time or schedule it on regular intervals. But if your requirement is more complicated you should check out [Advance Python Schedular](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree `cron` is better. But when you want to choose a solution, you should consider the specific requirement. Sometimes you can use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to do this.

Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.